# What is $z$ in this state space model? - Robust control

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter, robotics

There is two types of state space models:

The classic one:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu + \omega$$
$$y = Cx + Du + \upsilon $$

Where $A$ is the system matrix, $B$ is the insignal matrix, $C$ is the output matrix, $D$ is the direct matrix, $\omega$ is the disturbance vector and $\upsilon$ is the noise vector. Normaly those vectors often are multiplied with a diagonal matrix.

Then we have the...other state space model:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu + \omega$$
$$ z = Mx + D_z u $$
$$y = Cx + D_y u + \upsilon $$

So...what are 
$$ z = Mx + D_z u $$

supposed to be? Let me guess! The $z$ variable is only for loop shaping controllers which look like this:

[image]

And this:
$$y = Cx + D_y u + \upsilon $$

Is only for measurement and this:

$$ z = Mx + D_z u $$

Is only for optimizing showing which state are the state who going to the observable state?

For example:

If $C$ are:

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

And we want to measure all states $x$ just by one state. Let's say $x_3$.
That means that $M$ are going to be:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Right?
So the classical state space model's $C$ matrix is the new $M$ matrix?

Comment: I assume this question is in the context of $H_\infty$?

Comment: Not actually. I want to separate them. H-inf for one question and state space models for the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance variables, i.e. the variables you actually want to control, in contrast to $y$ which are the measured signals.

Comment: Tack Johan. So let's say that I have a state vector $x \in \Re^4$ and $x_2$ is the velocity from $x_1$ and $x_1$ is the position. Also $x_3$ is a position and $x_4$ is the velocity of that position. My goal is to control all the positions: $x_1$ and $x_3$. That means $M$ will be $M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &  0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ ? And the $D_z$ must be the same as $B$ ? I'm reading the book "Reglerteori av Torkel Glad och Lennart Ljung".

Comment: Or if I want to control the whole vector $x$, why not set $M$ as an indentity matrix?

Comment: If you want to do standard LQ minimizing $z^Tz = x^TQx + u^TRu$, you would have $M = \begin{pmatrix}Q^{1/2}\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $D_z = \begin{pmatrix}0\\R^{1/2}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But this is for H infinity control. Have a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380221/is-this-h-infty-robust-control I already know how to create LQG controllers :)

Comment: What ever. $z$ are the variables you have performance requirements on (such as limited   $H_{2}$ or $H_{\infty}$ norm from $w$)

Comment: So the $M$ matrix describe what states I want to control in the system and $D_z$ matrix describe what inputs effects the system? I only need to add the scalars 1 or 0 in $M$, the same as $D_z$ ? According to "Reglerteori - Flervariabla metoder" by Lennart Ljung and Torkel glad, the $z$ variable only describe the control units, but the book does not have $M$ as a full identity matrix for some reasons...

Comment: Or the $M$ matrix only describe what's the most important control units I need to focus on?

Comment: My goal is to find $S$ from this equation. But it requries a $M$ too. $$A^TS + SA + M^TM + S(\gamma^{-2} NN^T -BB^T)S = 0$$

Comment: $M$ and $D_z$ describe which linear combinations of $x$ and $u$ you have performance requirements on.

Comment: $z$ is not the control unit, it is the *controlled* unit, i.e., the signal you have requirements on. $M$ being the identity would be one special case,probably not very common as it would imply $z = x + D_zu$, i.e. $z$ is either only the states (dangerous as that would mean we don't care about inputs) or only a sum of states and inputs (not very common).

Comment: I don't understanding what you mean by performance? Sure, I know that that word means. Is it more like what states I want to prior more than other? Like $M$ is a tuning weighting matrix in the same way $Q$ and $R$ are  tuning weighting matrices for LQR controllers?

Comment: The thing you minimize. If you do LQ, $z$ is obvious as above. If you do loop-shaping as you talk about in the other post, it is the signal composed of the 3 outputs from your weight functions, $x$ is not just your physical states, it includes all states arising from filters and modelling the performance objective.

Comment: Yes! I'm going do loop shaping and I have my transfer function weighting matrices $W_S(s)$, $W_T(s)$ and $W_{ u}(s)$. By then...I can create my $M$ matrix?

Comment: This is from an example 10.1 in the book "Reglerteori". If I have a transfer function $G(s) = \frac{20}{s(s+1)}$ I can transform that to state space: $\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
20\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} \\
y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}x$ And let's say that I have found my weighting matrices $W_S(s) = 2/s, W_T(s) = 0.5, W_u(s) = 3$. That means my state space model are going to be

Comment: $$ \dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
1 & -1 &0 \\ 
 0& 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
20\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}u + \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} \omega \\
z = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 0.5 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &2 
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} \\

y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &0 
\end{bmatrix} x + \omega $$

Comment: If I say that $x_3 = W_S(s)(Gu + \omega)$

Comment: Or is it $$ \dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
1 & -1 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
20\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}u + \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} \omega \\
z = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 0.5 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &2 
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} \\

y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &0 
\end{bmatrix} x + \omega $$

Comment: I know that $$z_1 = W_u(s)u $$ $$z_2 = W_T(s)Gu$$  $$z_3 = W_S(s)(Gu+\omega)$$ $$y = Gu + \omega$$ But I can't understanding why $\omega$ and $u$ is left behind.

Comment: Sorry, are left behind compered to $$z = Mx + D_z u$$

Comment: I think I got this now. I know understanding what the $M$ matrix and $D_z$ matrix are and the $W_S(s)$ will always give an extra state. Example: $$W_u(s) = 5, W_T(s) = 0.5,  W_S(s) = \frac{2}{s} $$ and our state space model $$\dot{x_1} = -x_1 + u$$ will give us: $$z_1 = W_u(s)u = 5u $$ $$z_2 = W_T(s)Gu = 0.5x1$$ and one extra state $$z_3 = W_S(s)(Gu + \omega) = x_2 $$ That means $$x_2 = \frac{2}{s}(Gu +\omega)$$ and $$\dot{x_2} =2 (Gu + \omega) $$ Correct me if I'm wrong. We always add $$\frac{1}{s}$$ to the sensitivity  matrix $W_S(s)$ so the $H_\infty$ controller can have integration?

Comment: yes, integral in filter to have integral action (but in reality solvers have problem with that as so you have to move it into the LHP)

Comment: Move it...? What it? the state $x_2$?

Comment: using 1/(s+eps) instead

Comment: Oh! I see, then s must be negative or else the system will be unstable, but will have a lot of oscillations. But how sould I create the $M$ matrix if $W_T, W_U, W_S$ have transfer functions into it? The riccati equation do not like that.

Comment: You already had $W_S$ as a transfer function, so no difference

Comment: So if $W_s(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 3s + 5}$ and $W_T(s) = 1$ and $W_U(s) = 4$ then $z_3$ will be $z_3 = \frac{1}{s^2 + 3s + 5}(Gu + \omega)$. The problem is I cannot find the $M$ matrix.

Comment: You ill have to do the full state-space realization with 2 more states than you had in the original model $\ddot {z_3} + 3\dot{z_3} + 5z_3 = x_2 + w$. You're simply series-connecting two linear systems

Comment: Ok. Is it often that $W_S(s), W_U(s), W_T(s)$ contains kind of those transfer functions? Or is it very common that $W_S(s), W_U(s), W_T(s)$ is just a number, exept $W_S(s)$ which often has an integrator $\frac{1}{s}$

Comment: they are typically general low/high-pass filters

Comment: Is there no manual how to create the $M$ matrix? Let's say that I have this: $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 -5& -5 & 3 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
 0& -3 &-4  & -3
\end{bmatrix} , B = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
4\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}, N = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}, W_S(s) = \frac{5}{s+3}, W_T(s) = 4, W_U(s) = 7 $$. Now I need to compute the $M$ matrix.

Comment: No, you have to learn how to derive the state-space model for two connected systems.

Comment: Hi again! I thought that  $\omega$ was the disturbbance. But $\omega$ is: $$\omega = \begin{bmatrix}
d\\ 
r\\ 
n
\end{bmatrix}$$ And in this case, the  $$\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 = W_U(s)u\\ 
z_2 = W_T(s)Gu\\ 
z_3 = W_S(s)(Gu+ \omega) \\
y =  -\omega - Gu
\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\omega = -r$$ Not the disturbance. Problem solved! I was fooled by the book. But my new book is much better.